# How to detect routing to same page in Angular2?

Tags: angular

I have a search in my navbar that simply uses the router to pass the query in the route and navigates to the right component.

So basically for the search button in my navbar component:

```
onSubmit() {
  this.router.navigate(['/search', { query: this.searchQuery }]);
}
```

and then in the target search component:

```
this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
  doSearch(params['query']);
}
```

While this works perfectly when I change my query, it does not when the query does not change. I understand that with the subscription to the params Observable I do not get notified when the params stay the same. And the router just reuses the already loaded component so I cannot use any code in ngOnInit because it is not called.

The problem is that just because the search query is the same, the result might not be. So I need a way to call doSearch again, even with the same parameter.

Is there any way to detect when the router routes to the same destination without any parameter changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you subscribe to the `this.router.events` observable you will get notified even when the query remains the same.

Comment: thanks, got it working using those events. It feels however more like a workaround than a real solution.